# Why do magnetic effects not increase without a limit?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

Charges can only move at speed less than c. That limits the current in a wire with a given number of free electrons to some value. X amperes of current is a maximum possible current in that wire.

Maximum possible magnetic field strength next to a wire is proportional to the maximum possible current in the wire.

So my question is: Why does the magnetic field strength not increase without a limit as the relativistic length-contraction and other relativistic effects increase without a limit as the speed of charges approaches the speed of light?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason they don’t increase without limit is your assumption that the number of free electrons is limited. This may be true in matter but it isn’t true for, say, a beam of electrons. In classical EM you can have an arbitrarily large current density and an arbitrarily large magnetic field.

Answer (score 0):

The current-carrying capacity of wires is not limited by the speed of light. It is limited by the maximum temperature rise caused by ohmic heating in the wire that the insulation of the wire can withstand.

Minimization of loss is accomplished by reducing the resistance of the wire- by increasing its cross-sectional area.

The strength of the magnetic field can be magnified by looping the wire into a *coil*; the resulting field strength then scales as (number of loops of wire) x (current in the wire).

Adding loops of wire both increases the DC resistance of the resulting coil, thereby increasing its self-heating, and increases the physical size of the coil, limiting its ability to rid itself of that heat. Practical considerations like these impose limits on how strong a magnetic field you can build using electricity, wire, and insulation.

Answer (score 0):

Magnetic field at any point is determined by values of current everywhere, not by how strong relativistic effects such as length contraction are. You could only detect such contraction if you could observe the mobile charges' distances in their rest frame. In the lab frame where the wire is, the lengths are largely the same whether current is zero or very high.

On the microscopic level, charges, positions and velocities of the particles determine magnetic field at any point.